# Replace fonts of third party website to my custom fonts to be displayed on my app using Xamarin Webview

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i am using WebView to display multiple external websites each website has its unique/different fonts i want to display my custom font on each website which are loaded in my app's WebView so that apps looks same on each page.

I want to display each website with 1 single font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS and Android have different font-family.For example they don't support  **MicrosoftYaHei** .In iOS ,the dafault font is **Helvetica** and in android is **Droid Sans** .So I do not suggest you to do it.

If you do want to implement it you can use `CustomRenderer` to set it in two platforms.

> in iOS

```
using System;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView),typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer,IUIWebViewDelegate
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(NativeView!=null)
            {
                WeakDelegate = this;
            }
        }

        [Export("webViewDidFinishLoad:")]
        public void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
        {
            NSString htmlStr = new NSString("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily='PingFangSC-Light';");
            webView.EvaluateJavascript(htmlStr);
        }

    }
}
```

> in Android

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {

                Android.Webkit.WebView webview =(Android.Webkit.WebView) Control;
                WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;
                settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webview.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient());

            }

        }

    }



    public class JavascriptWebViewClient : WebViewClient

    {

        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)

        {

            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

            view.EvaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily='xxx';", null);
        }

    }


}
```